# partial correlations

Tags: self-study, correlation, statistical-significance, partial-correlation

Our CGPA (Variable 1) is influenced by Intelligence (Variable 2) ,and examination self -efficacy (variable 3) . Zero order correlations between these three variables are: r12= .50, r13= .60 and r23= .45. Use appropriate analysis to establish that what proportion of CGPA is influenced by Intelligence and examination self-efficacy at 0.05 level of significance. The above correlations were obtained on 120 sample.

edit:

I understood that we have to use multiple correlations to find the proportion of CGPA influenced by the 2 factors. I want to know the formula for multiple correlation and calculate the significance.

Comment: Check this out, it might help. http://www.real-statistics.com/correlation/multiple-correlation/#:~:text=Observation%3A%20Definition%201%20defines%20the,variables%20x%2C%20y%20and%20z.&text=The%20multiple%20correlation%20coefficient%20for,RSquare(R1%2C%20k)).